# How to load files dynamically in JupyterNotebooks?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is it possible to notify file changes to JupyterNotebook process? In my notebook, I load some functions or classes like below.

```
from my_file import my_func
```

Then, I edit my_file.py via other editor like VSCode. I want JupyterNotebook to load `my_file.py` again. 
So far, JupyterNotebook load old `my_file.py` even I run below cell again after the edit. I have to restart JupyterNotebook process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself. I just declare below first.

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

See more information.

- https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html

> %autoreload 2
>
> Reload all modules (except those excluded by %aimport)
>   every time before executing the Python code typed.